# Why does my html email appear differently when sent by AWS SES?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, email, encoding, utf

I've been working on some custom html email templates. I'm having some trouble with my emails appearing differently when they are sent by different email services. I'm using AWS SES to send these emails to clients.

I've been using [Postdrop](https://app.postdrop.io) to send test emails while I've been creating the template. Now that the AWS SES environment has been set up for my application, I can now send emails using the html template. The problem I'm getting is that when I send emails using AWS, the emails look different than they do when sent by Postdrop, even when viewing the email from the same email client.

I used a code checker to see how what the email client was receiving was different for each email sender, and they seem almost exactly the same, except for some Unicode(I think it's Unicode?) differences. The only differences I noted was that SES adds `=E2=80=8B` between certain sections of code, while Postdrop adds an empty line in place of that, and a short section of code where Postdrop included `=2E` at the start of some of the classes, where SES did not(This is the "External Class" section shown in the picture.) It seems like these are related to tab or end-line characters, but I'm not sure. There is other Unicode code used as well, but both emails use the same code in those sections.

**Here is an example of the input code:**

[image]

**And here is what I'm getting from the different email senders:**

[image]

These slight differences are causing the email sent by SES to appear incorrectly. Specifically, some of the media queries aren't working(while some still do), and there is additional spacing at the top.

In the header of the emails, both say they are being encoded by UTF-8, although the way it's phrased is slightly different.

Postdrop appears like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8" Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

and SES appears like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

Not sure if that would affect anything. What is causing this issue, and how do I fix it?

**Edit**

Here is the code for the Lambda function that tells SES to send the email, but some of the identifying stuff(specific email addresses, amazon region, and file structure) have been removed just for safety:

```
import boto3
import logging
import os
import sys
from emailbody import body
from emailbodytext import bodytext
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def send_email(recipients):
    SENDER = "" # must be verified in AWS SES Email
    RECIPIENTS = recipients # must be verified in AWS SES Email

    AWS_REGION = ""

    # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

    # Try to send the email.
    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = client.send_templated_email(
            Destination={
                'ToAddresses': RECIPIENTS,
            },
            Template='TemplateName',
            TemplateData = "{}",
            Source=SENDER
        )
    # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
        print(response['MessageId'])

def delete_email_template(templateToDelete):
    
    AWS_REGION = ""
    
    # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)
    
    # Try to get the email template.
    try:
        #Provide the contents of the email.
        response = client.delete_template(
            TemplateName=templateToDelete
        )
        return response

    # Display an error if something goes wrong. 
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        print(response['MessageId'])

def create_email_template():

    AWS_REGION = ""

    #The name for the template
    TEMPLATENAME = "Test"
    
    # The subject line for the email.
    SUBJECT = "Test Email"
    
    #The email body
    EMAILBODY = body
    
    #The email text
    BODYTEXT = bodytext
    
    # Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
    client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)

    #Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.create_template(
        Template={
            'TemplateName': TEMPLATENAME,
            'SubjectPart': SUBJECT,
            'TextPart': BODYTEXT,
            'HtmlPart': EMAILBODY
        }
    )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    emails = ['', '']
    create_email_template()
    send_email(emails)
    delete_email_template("Test")
```

Comment: SES isn't going to magically add the invalid characters.  Something in your code / input has those characters in there.  Postdrop is encoding the `.` sometimes - not always.  Let's see the code you used to generate this.

Comment: I showed a sample of the input code of the actual email. Do you mean the code being used to tell SES to send the email, or the rest of the html? Not sure which code you're asking for. I assumed the characters were being added by Unicode or SES settings, not the code, like how it adds "=" or "=3D" at parts, but I don't know much about Unicode.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the code that interacts with SES - is it via one of the AWS SDKs?  I feel that there is either bad data in the file you're sending (if, for example, you read the file from the file system) or the code that sends it is adding something.  A screenshot of the file isn't enough information as the editor may not display things it doesn't know how to.

Comment: Gotcha. We are using a lambda function to have SES send the emails. I will add that information to the questions.

Comment: @stdunbar I added the lambda function to the question text.

Comment: The `=E2=80=8B` string is *Mime Quoted-Printable* representation of `​` (U+200B,  *Zero Width Space*) (UTF-8 byte sequence `0xE2`,`0x80`,`0x8B`), and analogously: `=2E` means `.` (U+002E,  *Full Stop*)…

Comment: @stdunbar Turns out you were right about the bad file data. Turns out that bad data wasn't coming from the file code itself, or AWS, but from copying the code from Slack's code previewer! It has invisible lines that were adding those strange non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem today, and it's a silly one. The issue has nothing to do with the code or AWS. The non-ASCII characters that are being added are from Slack! Apparently if you copy html from Slack's code viewer directly, it adds additional characters for styling, which also happen to be non-ASCII characters. That explains why the emails were showing up incorrectly, as well as why it appeared that it was an encoding issue.

Thank you to everyone for all the additional contextual information.

I'm sure I'm not the only one that this Slack issue has affected, so I will let Slack know about this bug.

UPDATE: I contacted Slack and they already have this on the list of bugs to squash so hopefully a fix will come soon.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the `quoted-printable` encoding of your email. This encoding will convert any non allowed character to a `=..=...` hex sequence. As described [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html). This encoding gets then parsed by the final mail client (or probably by a server in case of web mail like Gmail) and displayed to the end reader. As discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1237545/characters-in-email-displayed-like-e2-80-99) this parsing process is not very reliable.

`=E2=80=8B` is actually the encoding of a [zero width space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm). So you have junk (invisible spaces) inside your email. Postdrop is probably just stripping them where SES not.

Regarding the solution I would advise against non ASCII characters in your email, or at least inside the CSS portion of it as if would make the parsing very unpredictable. Otherwise you may try with other `Content-Transfer-Encoding`s.

Comment: I downloaded the highlight-bad-chars package for my Atom editor to check for any zero width space characters. I verified that the package is working and that it highlights the zero width characters. I know that the email template does not contain any non ascii characters, and that there are none added by the CSS inline(I checked both). So somewhere either in our function call to SES, or by SES itself, the characters are being added. I will play around with different encoding options, and double check our function calls.

Comment: I would blame it on SES as a last resort. It is very unlikely they have such behaviour and has never been reported before.

Comment: To further help we would need some actual raw data of templates, sent mails, and received mails, together with raw headers and client versions.

Comment: I will add that data to the question. Is there any information in the header that could be identifying, and should be hidden before I share it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to minify that HTML email template. There are some tools for this. Even though both are sending your email, AWS is just messing it up in the process of trying to make adjustments.... Emails are very sensitive to charecter encoding. Most HTML template creating tools have a dev testing and then a build function that minifies and a bunch of other changes to the way CSS is written, even some make it all inline. That is not a valid HTML/CSS template for email.

Also not sure UTF-8 is what you want:
Encoding (string) --

```
The encoding: UTF-8   but may not preserve all special characters when a message was encoded with a different encoding format. Base64 preserves all special characters. The default value is UTF-8.
```